# Find linearly dependent columns via Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $A$ has the form:
$ A =  
\begin{bmatrix}
  A_{11} & A_{12} \\
  A_{21} & A_{22}
 \end{bmatrix}
$. Where $A$ is $k \times k$, and that $k$ steps of Gaussian elimination without interchanges have been successfully completed.

a) Show that column $j$ of the $(n-k)(n-k)$ remaining matrix is a linear combination of the $jth$ column of $A_{22}$ and the $k$ columns of $A_{21}$.

b)Using part **a**, show that a zero first column of the remaining matrix at the beginning of the step $k$ of Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting implies that the first $k$ columns of the original matrix are linearly dependent(and hence the original matrix is singular).

This question is my homework, But I don’t understand the first part. Isn’t $A_{22} $ a $(n-k)(n-k)$ matrix? So it would be the remaining matrix (Am I right?). And since we are doing Gaussian elimination $A_{21}$ should be $0$. Then what does part **a** mean?

Comment: Ask your teacher. (We can't help you. For instance, do the $A_{i,j}$s represent $A$ before Gaussian elimination, or after fixing the first $k$ columns?)

Comment: They mean the original values in those columns, not the ones after partial row-reduction.